# What is the use of these two method in volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am following this tutorial from the site https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/networking/android-volley-tutorial/ - I understand almost everything properly, except these two method of `Singleton` class.

Is there anyone who can help me to understand these method properly.
I want to know about the method.

```
 public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req,String tag){
        req.setTag(tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
    public ImageLoader getImageLoader(){
        return mImageLoader;
    }
    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag){
        if(mRequestQueue!=null){
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
```

My Singleton class is....

```
public class MySingleton2 {
    private static MySingleton2 mInatance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private Context mContext;

    private MySingleton2(Context context) {
        this.mContext=context;
        mRequestQueue=getRequestQueue();
        mImageLoader=new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String,Bitmap>
            cache=new LruCache<>(20);
            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton2 getInstance(Context context) {
        if(mInatance==null) {
            mInatance=new MySingleton2(context);
        }

        return mInatance;
    }

    public  RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if(mRequestQueue==null) {
            mRequestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext.getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader(){
        return mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req,String tag){
        req.setTag(tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag){
        if(mRequestQueue!=null){
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Any Kind of help is appreciated ......

Answer (score 1):

These methods are self-explanatory, but here goes:

Volley uses a request queue and you can add multiple requests to that queue. The method `addToRequestQueue` is used for that. By-default, upto 4 requests are executed in parallel by Volley, so if you make more than 4 requests, they would wait for other requests to finish execution.

The method `cancelPendingRequests` is used to cancel all the requests with a specific tag. You may want to cancel these pending requests in special situations only, like while exiting an Activity, you may want to cancel all the requests that were made to load images specific to that activity